# Rounding a value to only a list of certain values in C#

Tags: c#, .net, math

I have a list of double values, I want to Round a variable's value to only that list of numbers

Example:

The list contents are: {12,15,23,94,35,48}

The Variable's value is 17, So it will be rounded to 15

If The variable's value is less than the least number, it will be rounded to it, if it's value is larger than the largest number, it will be rounded to it.

The list contents is always changing according to an external factor, So I cannot hardocde the values I Want to round up or down to.

How can do it in C# ?

Comment: Work out the difference between unrounded values and possible results. Store these differences in a dictionary keyed by possible result and select the result with the lowest difference.

Comment: How big can this collection be? Otherwise you should consider using a sorted collection and using binary search.

Comment: As Seven said, especially if your list is static (doesn't change)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a method using LINQ:

```
var list = new[] { 12, 15, 23, 94, 35, 48 };
var input = 17;

var diffList = from number in list
               select new {
                   number,
                   difference = Math.Abs(number - input)
               };
var result = (from diffItem in diffList
              orderby diffItem.difference
              select diffItem).First().number;
```

**EDIT**: Renamed some of the variables so the code is less confusing...

**EDIT**:

The `list` variable is an implicitly declare array of `int`. The first LINQ statement `diffList` defines an anonymous type that has your original number from the list (`number`) as well as the difference between it and your current value (`input`).

The second LINQ statement `result` orders that anonymous type collection by the difference, which is your "rounding" requirement. It takes the first item in that list as it will have the smallest difference, and then selects only the original `.number` from the anonymous type.

Comment: +1. It's more efficient than my solution since it only loops `values` once.

Comment: Works like a charm, although I cannot understand all of it :)

Comment: @AndersAbel: Actually, rather twice, if not more. First to get the differences. Then to order.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: You're right, especially the sorting implementation of `OrderBy` will have a large impact on the performance.

Answer (score 6):

*Assuming the array is sorted*, you could perform a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) in the array, narrowing it down to which two numbers the given number lies between.

Then once you have these two numbers, you simply round to the nearest of the two.

```
static int RoundToArray(int value, int[] array) {
    int min = 0;
    if (array[min] >= value) return array[min];

    int max = array.Length - 1;
    if (array[max] <= value) return array[max];

    while (max - min > 1) {
        int mid = (max + min) / 2;

        if (array[mid] == value) {
            return array[mid];
        } else if (array[mid] < value) {
            min = mid;
        } else {
            max = mid;
        }
    }

    if (array[max] - value <= value - array[min]) {
        return array[max];
    } else {
        return array[min];
    }

}
```

Comment: Not only assuming, if this is supposed to work on big collections, a sorted collection is the way to go.

Comment: In practice of course it does not matter, but I note that you are doing the "dangerous" way of finding the midpoint of two integers. If min + max happens to overflow to negative then half that is a negative number. See this article for an entertaining analysis of the problem and its possible solutions: http://locklessinc.com/articles/binary_search/

Answer (score 2):

Using linq:

```
int value = 17;
var values =  new float[] { 12, 15, 23, 94, 35, 48 };
if(value < values.First()) return value.First();
if(value > values.Last()) return value.Last();

float below = values.Where(v => v <= value).Max();
float above = values.Where(v => v >= value).Min();

if(value - below < above - value)
  return below;
else
  return above;
```

As long as then number of possible values is quite small this should work. If you have thousands of possible values another solution should be used, which takes advantage of `values` being sorted (if it really is sorted).

Comment: Error 1 'int' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the array of numbers and set a *roundedNum* variable equal to each one **if** a variable *delta* is less than the current lowest *delta*. Some things are best described in code.

```
int roundedNum = myNum;
int delta = myArray[myArray.Length-1] + 1;

for(int i=0; i<myArray.Length; ++i) {
    if(Math.Abs(myNum - myArray[i]) < delta) {
        delta = Math.Abs(myNum - myArray[i]);
        roundedNum = myArray[i];
    }
}
```

That should do the trick quite nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
double distance = double.PositiveInfinity;
float roundedValue = float.NaN;
foreach (float f in list)
{
    double d = Math.Abs(d - f);
    if (d < distance)
    {
        distance = d;
        roundedValue = f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple rounding down in linq

```
    public decimal? RoundDownToList(decimal input, decimal[] list)
    {
        var result = (from number in list
                      where number <= input
                      orderby number descending
                      select number).FirstOrDefault();

        return result;
    }
```